# Data truncation: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'idFactura' at row 1

Tags: java

Al ejecutar mi aplicación en java, me funciona todo perfecto sin que nada lo altere, pero sale ese pequeño detalle, ¿A que se deberá?, ya que deriva a un campo de la tabla de la base de datos.

La tabla se llama Factura.

Botón Guardar (Código JAVA):

```
Connection con=null;
        try{
            con=getConnection();
            ps=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO factura (idFactura, Precioneto, precioIVA, costoIVA, fechaCompra, HoraCompra, Distribuidor, MetodoPago) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            ps.setString(1, txtid.getText());
            if(txtid.getText().equals("")){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Rellenar campo ID");
            }
            ps.setString(2, txtPrecioNeto.getText());
            if(txtPrecioNeto.getText().equals("")){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Rellenar campo Precio Neto");
            }
            ps.setString(3, txtPrecioIVA.getText());
            if(txtPrecioIVA.getText().equals("")){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Rellenar campo Precio IVA");
            }
            ps.setString(4, txtCostoIVA.getText());
            if(txtCostoIVA.getText().equals("")){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Rellenar campo Costo IVA");
            }
            ps.setString(5, txtFechaCompra.getText());
            if(txtFechaCompra.getText().equals("")){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Rellenar campo Fecha de Compra");
            }
            ps.setString(6, txtHoraCompra.getText());
            if(txtHoraCompra.getText().equals("")){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Rellenar campo Hora de Compra");
            }
            ps.setString(7, txtDistribuidor.getText());
            if(txtDistribuidor.getText().equals("")){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Rellenar campo Distribuidor");
            }
            ps.setString(8, txtPago.getText());
            if(txtPago.getText().equals("")){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Rellenar campo Pago");
            }
            int res=ps.executeUpdate();
            if(res>0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se ejecuto correctamente");
                limpiarCajas();
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al ejecutar la conexion");
                limpiarCajas();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println(e);
        }
```

Comment: hola @nicolasyo1WWE podrias colocarlo en modo codigo para poder facilitar la lectura. gracias

Comment: Perdón no me había dado cuenta, ahí si.

Comment: La columna `idFactura` parece ser de tipo `Integer`, pero al momento de ajustar el parámetro le pasas un `String`: `ps.setString(1, txtid.getText());`. ¿Verificaste el tipo de dato?

Comment: no se como tienes configurado lo demas, pero normalmente en esta linea iria un 0 en vez de un 1 `ps.setString(1, txtid.getText());`

Comment: @AsdrubalHernandez, en este caso, los parámetros se comienzan a contar desde el índice `1`. Lo dice la documentación: [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString(int,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: Aparte del error cuya solución ya ha sido indicada en la respuesta, debes revisar la lógica de tu programa. El que tú settes el valor a un statement antes de verificarlo indica un claro error de lógica. O sea, hacer algo así: `ps.setString(1, txtid.getText());
            if(txtid.getText().equals("")){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Rellenar campo ID");
            }` no es bueno. Aunque el usuario introduzca el dato, ya tú seteaste el valor vacío en el statement. Lo correcto sería recoger cada dato, verificar y luego setear únicamente si todo está bien.

Answer (score 1):

La solucion es convertir a integer esta line

```
ps.setString(1, txtid.getText());
```

algo asi:

```
ps.setInteger(1, Integer.parseInt(txtid.getText()));
```

Comment: Debería ser así: `ps.setInteger(1, Integer.parseInt(txtid.getText()));`. Sino el tipo de dato en la base de datos seguiría siendo erróneo.

Comment: si, estas en lo correcto. se me paso la otra parte

Comment: Trata de editar la pregunta, así no habría problema al intentar usar la solución.

Comment: listo @C.Rodriguez

Comment: Al modificarlo como lo mencionaron ustedes, me sale de esta manera ahora, java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""